# How long should I steam squid and cuttlefish?

Tags: cooking-time, seafood

I have read that the squid and cuttlefish are more tender if they are cooked in less than 3 minutes in a pan. But what about steam cooking, how much time does it need?

Answer (score 2):

I have always found that squid needs to be only cooked for 1 minute (2-3 minutes if battered and deep fried). Any more or any less results in very rubbery texture.

It can also be slow cooked for an hour or more in a soup so that it becomes tender.

Comment: 1 minute or an hour? Big difference there...

Comment: Absolutely, squid really only needs a minute to be fully cooked (i.e. 1 minute of quick cooking in a pan or frying) going over that in the 2 - 59 minute range results in squid that is barely edible and very rubbery. If you cook it for an hour in a braise or soup the hour of cooking will break down the collagen in the squid resulting in a once again tender squid with a completely different taste and texture then if you had quickly cooked it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, I'll edit your answer a bit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Squid etc are tender if cooked very quickly or for a long time. In between = rubber, inedibility